# regex match span or a?

Tags: php, regex

I have this function:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0){
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Passing for example `span` as parameter `$tagname` allows me to match any span tags. I would expect passing `a|span` would allow me to mach any `a` or `span` tags. But it doesn't match anything. Why?

Comment: Suggestion: use [`XPath / DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: Probably preg_quote your pattern before preg_match

Comment: What is a source example that fails? Instead of `if(count($matches) > 0){` just `if` the `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with grouping in parenthesis (as we talk in comments):

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<($tagname)?.*>(.*)<\/($tagname)>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0){
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

If you pass `$string = "a|span"` you'll obtain `$pattern = "/<(a|span)>";`

Comment: this won't match <span class="vcard author">Henrik Henriksson</span> with pattern patter a|span?

Comment: It matches the same as you write (`?.*`). The only difference with your code is the brackets `[]` to group a collection of allowed strings separated by a `|`

Comment: `[]` is a character class, it allows individual characters, not the group. This would allow `s`, `p`, `a`, `n`, `|`, and `a` again.

Comment: @Himmators update your question to have example strings.

Comment: @Himmators You used the right thing on it. The `[]` suggested will not only match a,span but a,span,snap,pans, etc

Comment: @Himmators so this question is resolved? You seem to only be addressing this answer and not the comments on your question..

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's true, it's a pattern search `()`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have forgetfulness